# How to execute only page URL and redirect to another page?

Tags: php, redirect

I want to execute an URL then page will redirect to requested header location. But page not redirect. My previous page is showing here.

See my code-

**example.php**

```
<?php
function test() {
    $aa = 'good morning';
    //file_get_content('http://localhost/DemoProject/test.php');
    $ch = curl_init('http://localhost/DemoProject/test.php');
    curl_exec($ch);
    return $aa;
}
$text = test();
header('location:http://www.google.co.in/search?q='.urlencode($text));
?>
```

In `test.php` file I have written one pdf generated code and email function  with generate PDF file attachment. I want only `http://localhost/DemoProject/test.php` execute.

When I run `example.php` file. That page will redirect to `http://www.google.co.in/search?q=good+morning` this is showing current page with `test.php` data.

How to only execute URL not retrieve any data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the output not sent to the browser by setting the option `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`

```
$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/DemoProject/test.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answeing. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding exit statement after the header() statement, which would then make your code look like,

```
<?php
function test() {
    $aa = 'good morning';
    //file_get_content('http://localhost/DemoProject/test.php');
    $ch = curl_init('http://localhost/DemoProject/test.php');
    curl_exec($ch);
    return $aa;
}
$text = test();
header('location:http://www.google.co.in/search?q='.urlencode($text));
exit;
?>
```

Here is the PHP documentation that states that adding exit will stop all other code execution and redirect to the URL.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Also make sure that there is no output written before the header() is called, i.e. do not echo or have blank lines present that would get outputted before the header().